# Play 2.0 - Scala - How Add dependencies for any JDBC Drivers

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

can somebody tell me how can I add a MSSQL driver dependence to a Play 2 App?

I have this settings working...

```
db.default.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=test;user=test;password=test;"
```

Edited: I know that in the file project/Build.scala must be the statement for this with a line like this:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
"" % "" % ""
)
```

But I don't know how must be filled these strings and I would like know that to be able to add any dependence type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that there are no repositories with the MSSQL JDBC drivers.

In this case, the correct, most reliable solution would be to put the .jars in the `lib` folder, this is what SBT calls "unmanaged dependency folder". Since there isn't a central place for this driver I'd also commit this jar along with the rest of the project in VCS.

Comment: Get current official MS SQL Server drivers here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write anything in `project/Build.scala`

1. Download and save Microsoft's driver (probably [`sqljdbc4.jar`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774)) in the `lib` folder (if you didn't it yet).
2. Configure connection in the `application.conf` (sample working for me with Azure)

   ```
   db.default.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
   db.default.url="jdbc:sqlserver://sOm3s3rVeR.database.windows.net:1433;database=your-db;encrypt=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30"
   db.default.user="account@sOm3s3rVeR"
   db.default.password="YOURpass123"

   # don't forget to uncomment that line: 
   ebean.default="models.*"
   ```

And that's all. Anyway I remember that I had some problems with Ebean 2.7.3 (default in Play 2.0.4) so I went with 2.7.5. Now it works.